# name conflict on chainweaver (pact)

Tags: pact

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv63a.png)

I am getting this error
`1:1definition name conflict: mint-kmp`

I did change the module name but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple functions or variables etc. with the name `mint-kmp` in your contract